# Query string on static resource on CDN

Tags: wordpress, cdn

I keep getting errors that some file may not be cached because they have query strings on my WP site. These files are hosted on MaxCDN. Here's an example

[image: query string on static files]

I have no idea why all the "x74177" strings are attached, there are 17 files like this, all CSS/js files.

Any idea how to remove them?

Comment: Those query strings are there because their function is to prevent caching of assets that may change frequently.

Comment: Oh, didn't think of it that way. But most of these are plugin CSS files that don't change till an update happens (which isn't very frequent)